# Javascript serverless error of json object with async return

Tags: javascript, httpresponse, serverless

First, I write lambda function like:

```
function jsonResponse(status, header, body) {
  return {
    headers: Object.assign(header, {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    }),
    statusCode: status,
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
  }
}

export const hello = async (event, context, cb) => { 
  const rep = {
      message: 'v1.0',
      event: event
  };
  cb(null, jsonResponse(201, {}, rep)); 
  return;
};
```

It work OK, but according the serverless forum [the serverless office forum](https://forum.serverless.com/t/how-to-change-status-code-of-headers-of-response/5878) and the [blog](http://www.goingserverless.com/blog/how-async-lambda-handlers-work-in-node-8-10)
The code should be

```
function createResponse(status, header, body) {
  return {
    headers: Object.assign(header, {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    }),
    statusCode: status,
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
  }
}

export const hello = async (event, context) => { 
  const rep = {
      message: 'v1.0',
      event: event
  };
  return createResponse(201, {}, rep);
};
```

For using the callback parameter as it’s not officially part of the async handler syntax.

I use the same version nodejs 8.10 as the article,
But When I apply the return function, I get 502 error:

```
{
"message": "Internal server error"
}
```

My serverless handler configuration:

```
functions:
  first:
    handler: handlers/first.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: first
          method: get
```

When I try to run it locally and it just keep running without any output for this handler.

Can you tell me why it is internal error and how to fix it?

Comment: Please use the Code Snippet button (`{}`) instead of backticks.

Comment: If you do not use any `await` keyword in a `async` function, please return a `Promise`. You could read more about async await of javascript. In your case, you can use `return await createResponse(201, {}, rep);` instead of `return createResponse(201, {}, rep);` (or `return Promise.resolve(createResponse(201, {}, rep)); ` - just return a promise).